# how to fix this error in bashrc

Tags: bash, alias

I added a list of alias to .bashrc and when I use . ~/.bashrc to refresh the list I get this error.

[image]

### list of alias I added:

```
alias a="sudo apt-get install"
alias c='printf "\033c"'
alias d="dpkg -i"
alias h="history"
alias if="ifconfig"
alias gb="leafpad ~/.bashrc"
alias gb1=". ~/.bashrc"
alias l="leafpad "
alias msf="msfconsole "
alias p="python "
alias r="recon-ng"
alias n="nautilus "
alias gc="git clone "
alias ap="apropos"
alias req="pip install -r requirements.txt"
alias exc="expressvpn connect"
alias exd="expressvpn disconnect"
alias exs="expressvpn status"
alias stor="service tor start "
alias tors="service tor stop "
alias fix="sudo apt-get clean ; sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get -f install"
```

Comment: `alias if="ifconfig"` will do something very bad to your shell. You should not replace bash's keywords.

Comment: I think my mistake was in this line:alias if="ifconfig"
you are right it's solved now

Comment: This is a place where it's safer to use functions than aliases: `if() { ifconfig "$@"; }` would have failed itself instead of replacing the meaning of `if`.